# How to set docker path for Jenkins local? docker: command not found

Tags: docker, selenium, jenkins, zalenium

I am trying to run Zalenium from Jenkins local installed on my Mac. I am able to execute tests locally from Eclipse by first spinning up docker from Terminal. Now I am trying to execute tests via pipeline.

Here's the pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
tools
{
    maven 'M2_HOME'
    jdk 'JAVA_HOME'
 }
    stages {
        stage('Code and Dependencies'){
            parallel{
            stage('Checkout Code'){
                steps{
                     git(url: 'https://github.com/xxxxx')
                }
            }
            
        stage('Initialise Tools') {
          steps {
            tool(name: 'M2_HOME', type: 'maven')
            tool(name: 'JAVA_HOME', type: 'jdk')
          }
        }
            
            stage('Install Dependencies'){
                steps{
                    sh 'docker pull elgalu/selenium'
                    sh 'docker pull dosel/zalenium'
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Global tools configuration:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
testuser@blr-ml-test ~ % which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker

testuser@blr-ml-test ~ % docker -v
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
```

But when I run the job, I get:

```
/Users/test/.jenkins/workspace/ZaleniumPipeline@tmp/durable-16989357/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
```

I am able to run from local Jenkins though. I suspect this is a path setting issue. Tried few similar questions but none worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

I am following this example: https://github.com/DevOpsPlayground/Hands-on-with-Continuous-Testing-using-Jenkins-and-Zalenium